# How to call another ctor?

Tags: c#, constructor

For example, in my class Foo has two ctor methods, how do I call parameterless ctor in another ctor?

```
class Foo {
   public Foo() {
      // initialized this class 
   }

   public Foo(int a, int b) {
      // initialized by Foo(), how do I call Foo() here ?

      .... // other initializing here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `: this()` between the parameter list and the opening brace:

```
class Foo {
   public Foo() {
   }

   public Foo(int a, int b) : this() {
   }
}
```

Comment: @Toro, you should also note that you can call base constructors the same way by using `base([param list])`

Comment: @Slugster, Thank you, I will note that.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the initializer list, like so:

```
public Foo(int a, int b) : this() {
          // initialized by Foo(), how do I call Foo() here ?

          .... // other initializing here
       }
```

Comment: What's the correct term in C# for the list of base class initializers?

Comment: I don't remember at the moment; I don't know if it has any particular names.